# How to apply filter after the retrieve methods?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I'm currently overriding the list method of the ModelViewSet and using filter_fields but I realized that the filter is applied before the list, so my list method is not being filtered by the query param. Is it possible to apply this filter after the list method?

```
class AccountViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer
    filter_fields = ('country__name')
    filter_backends = (django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    queryset = Account.objects.all()

    def list(self, request):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            queryset = Account.objects.all()
        else:
            bank_user = BankUser.objects.get(user=request.user)
            queryset = Account.objects.filter(bank=bank_user.bank)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

When I do request using this URL `http://localhost:8000/api/account/?country__name=Germany`, it returns all the accounts filtered by bank but not by country.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue. I had to apply the `filter_queryset` in the `queryset` of the ViewSet and use it. `queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())`